# Deep Link Kit regex for zero or more

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to use [Deep Link Kit](https://github.com/button/DeepLinkKit/blob/master/README.md) to route both of these paths:

```
myapp://page/2        // <- doesn't work
myapp://page/2/7      //<- works
```

The route handler I've registered at the moment is:

```
router.registerHandlerClass(AppRouteHandler.self, forRoute: "page/:number/:commentID(.*)")
```

I added the `(.*)` for the regex of zero or more comment IDs. However this doesn't seem to make any difference as it only works when you have both the `:number` and `:commentID` defined. I've also tried `myapp://page/2/` but that doesn't work either. Any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE**

One solution is to register the two routes separately:

```
router.registerHandlerClass(AppRouteHandler.self, forRoute: "page/:number")
router.registerHandlerClass(AppRouteHandler.self, forRoute: "page/:number/:commentID")
```

but ideally, I'd be able to use regex.

Answer (score 1):

I counter this problem too, after combine you solution I came up with this solution

```
router.registerHandlerClass(AppRouteHandler.self, forRoute: "page/:number/?:commentID(.*)")
```

That will ignore the second `/`, and your `commentID` will be set with empty string